# Phrase for a proponent of states' rights

Tags: orthography, apostrophe, epithet-requests, politics

What do you call someone who supports states' rights?

I often see some variation of "states' rightists" but I have a few uncertainties there.

1. Should there be an apostrophe? "States' rights" makes sense, because the rights belong to the several states. But a "rightist" doesn't belong to states; he or she just believes that states have rights. So would they be "states rightists"?
2. Is this an appropriate phrase for a formal text? My dictionary only defines "rightists" as the opposite of "leftists," and in no way indicates that a "rightist" is someone who supports a certain set of political rights. I see "animal rightist" in some dictionaries, but no "states rightist" or "states' rightest."

(Federalist doesn't work, because in early American history the federalists were the party of centralists and anti-federalists were the party of states' rights.)

Comment: "A Proponent of State's Rights"

Comment: @Oldcat: That's what I'm afraid of, as it's going to murder my word count.

Comment: Most proponents of state's/s' rights claim to be "strict constructionists" (to the extent that it suits their purpose), so maybe "strict constructionists re(garding) state's rights," but that's even longer.

Comment: If you’re using the term frequently in a paper/article/something and worry about word/character count, you can always the first time you mention them call them “State[’s/s’] Rights Proponents (henceforth SRPs)”, and then just use the _very_ brief “SRP(s)” the rest of the time.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you're trying to get across.  I'm assuming that, when talking about [states' rights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States%27_rights), you are talking about the rights of the individual states inside of the United States.  (However, I suppose you could be talking about states' rights in the sense of nation states' soveriegn rights. If this is the case, then my answers don't necessarily apply.)

*[Federalist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/federalist)* would never be the right term, because a federalist supports a strong federal government.  *Anti-federalist* may be the right term, because they oppose a strong federal government (which literally means a supporting state's rights over the federal government's rights).  However, while *[anti-federalist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/antifederalist)* would be exactly the right term while discussing early American history, today it carries a connotation similar to *[anarchist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anarchist)* or *anti-government* to a lay person.

As you discovered, *[rightist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rightist)*, in American discourse, always refers to conservatives, and generally is used disparagingly to imply that the person is extreme in their views.  Contrast to *[leftist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leftist)*, which applies to liberals.

Depending on exactly what you are writing, you may be able to turn the term *federalist* on it's head as *state federalist*.  However, such a phrase may be more apt as to describe the relationship between a state and her people, as opposed to a state and the federal government.

Some states' rights supporters fashion themselves (ironically) as *[Constitutionalists](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Constitutionalist)* based on the 10th Amendment and other clauses in the document, even though such a term is much broader in meaning.

However, in the end, I suppose that the simple "states' rights supporter" may be the best option.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with your definition of Federalists, but not of federalists. A federalist supports the division of sovereignty (and thus implicitly some level of states' rights) as opposed to a unified sovereignty (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federalism). Similarly, a supporter of states' rights is a federalist; a secessionist is not.

Comment: Supporting a division of sovereignty does not necessarily mean that person also supports states' rights.  For example, I may support the division between the federal government and the municipality, but not the intermediary division of "state".  Likewise, a secessionist says nothing of a support of states' rights.  I may believe that a national government is trampling my state's rights, which is why I want to secede.  Or, I may disagree with my national government's policies, so I want to secede.  It makes no difference; both are secessionists.

Answer (score 0):

A **devolutionist** or words relating to **devolution** seem to fit particularly well here, at least to my BrE mind, as devolution is often talked of in regard to the giving of more powers to the Scottish, Irish, Welsh( and other) assemblies.

> 4. (Government, Politics & Diplomacy) a transfer or allocation of authority, esp from a central government to regional governments or particular interests
>      ([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/devolutionist))

The same article also cites as a synonym

> decentralisation, distribution of power, surrender of power, relinquishment of power

The word is not specifically related to American states, but it is very common to hear of devolution and *devolutionism* would seem to follow on.

Comment: But no one in the US would know what you were talking about.

Comment: @HotLicks Possibly, but it is a relatively self-explanatory word and does fit quite nicely